# "Do you think it will take?" - how come it means to *succeed*?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm watching *Upload* in prime-video. An Actress was doing something (putting someone depressed to bed in VR, hoping that it will make him wake up happy again; but it really doesn't matter), and another actress asked "Do you think it will take?", meaning to ask whether she thinks this will work, will help. Minute 22 if of any help. Both the Hebrew and French translations seem to understand it the same as I did ("Ça marchera, tu crois?", and "?את חושבת שזה יצליח" - again, if of any help), but I've never heard such translation for take.

I just looked up all the entries of take in Oxford dictionary (as well as in Urban), and none refered to even a similar meaning.

**So: have you ever used *take* as *to succeed at doing something*, how common is that and could you kindly give an example for such usage?**

Comment: If you look at the [Merriam-Webster definition of *take*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take), the fifth definition of the *intransitive* sense of the verb is "to take effect : ACT, OPERATE," so this is a standard definition. I'd say it's not terribly common, but native speakers would recognize it.

Comment: I'd take the meaning to be to take *hold*, to take *root*, to hook on. Common in the New York area. To my ear, *to succeed* overstates the point, which is that the start took effect and caught on, not the end. Applied to a tree graft, an organ transplant, a seed beginning to germinate, a fertilized egg implanted. It took.

Comment: The OED sense 11a "Of a plant, cutting, seed, crop, etc.: to establish itself and begin to grow" dates to 1530 and possibly earlier. It also has sense 7a "Chiefly of a hook, tooth, or similar component: to engage with or fit into a corresponding part", with an example referring to a catch in a mechanism from 1730 (that's now "rare" but seems relevant).